# Excel minimizing after executing VBA

Tags: excel, windows-10, vba

I'm migrating my VBA code from one windows 10 machine to another (excel 2010 in this case).

Works perfectly on one laptop but when I run the code on the new machine (a surface pro), excel is minimized (or loses focus) and I'm left with the stupid app screen showing. Just an annoyance really, but it screws up my work flow.

Basically I open an input workbook and copy/paste into a template based workbook, then close the original workbook. I think this may be the point at which it minimizes the excel application, but I'm not sure.

Anyone have any tricks/tips?

Code Added:

```
ChDir "C:\Users\laing\Documents\Business\LMCI\LMCI_Templates"
Workbooks.Add Template:= _
    "C:\Users\laing\Documents\Business\LMCI\LMCI_Templates\Transfer_Form.xltm"

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ChDir "C:\Users\laing\Documents\Business\Processing_files"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "C:\Users\laing\Documents\Business\Processing_files\Transfer.xlsx", FileFormat _
    :=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Note: This happens with almost any code I run, the example here is just the latest one generating the glitch (and before you jump on me I know there's no error trapping here). Similar thing happens even if there is error trapping.

Comment: Add your VBA code to your question

Comment: Please add you answer as an answer and not as an edit to the question.

Comment: Sorry for the incorrect etiquette. Cleaned things up.

Answer (score 0):

Oy Vey!! Solved!

I should have realized that something was funky when a number of my applications were being flaky. Remember how I wrote that the new unit was a "Surface Pro"? Well turns out that the older versions of office don't like tablet mode. Disabled it in the Action Centre and presto problem solved. I discovered this while trying to research why my menu in the VBA Editor disappeared--special shout out in thanks to rick_danger (over on Experts Exchange) for the solution.